# Select rows with certain value in any of the columns

Tags: r

I got a dataframe where there is gene expression data

I'm trying to extract all rows where ANY of the columns has a value (data is already in log2 values) >= 2 but can't seem to get there. My data is:

```
      A B C D
Gene1 1 2 3 1
Gene2 2 1 1 4
Gene3 1 1 0 1
Gene4 1 2 0 1
```

I would only like to retain `gene1`, `gene2` and `gene4` without stating all columns (as this is just a toy example).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `rowSums` on a logical matrix derived from `df >=2` and double negate (`!`) to get the index of rows to subset.

```
df[!!rowSums(df >=2),]
#      A B C D
#Gene1 1 2 3 1
#Gene2 2 1 1 4
#Gene4 1 2 0 1
```

Or using the reverse condition `df <2` to get the logical matrix,  use`rowSums`, then check whether this is  less than `ncol(df)`

```
df[rowSums(df <2) < ncol(df),]
#     A B C D
#Gene1 1 2 3 1
#Gene2 2 1 1 4
#Gene4 1 2 0 1
```

Or

```
df[apply(t(df>=2),2, any), ]
```

#### data

```
df <- structure(list(A = c(1L, 2L, 1L, 1L), B = c(2L, 1L, 1L, 2L), 
 C = c(3L, 1L, 0L, 0L), D = c(1L, 4L, 1L, 1L)), .Names = c("A", 
"B", "C", "D"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("Gene1", 
"Gene2", "Gene3", "Gene4"))
```

Comment: Could you state what happens in your code? The last one seems to work the best but i'm not sure as my original data is quite large. Thanks for the answers anyways!

The last one seems to work but nevertheless i'm still interested in what you're doing exactly. I would like to extract the absolute values so I know where the values are > 2 or < -2. Big thanks!

Comment: @vds I am getting exactly the same results with both code.  Are you getting it differently?

Comment: As i tried again it worked with both solutions. Thanks a lot, I'm in my last year of bioinformatics and working on a huge project but I have very little experience in R. I can't thank you enough!

Comment: @vds If you split up the codes, you can easily understand the mechanism.  For example first try `df >=2`, then `rowSums(df >=2)`, `!rowSums(df >=2)`, and `!!rowSums(df >=2)`